# PS3 won't read / recognize any disks after 3.70 firmware upgrade

Tags: ps3

My fat 80GB PS3 suddenly stopped recognizing gaming and BD movie disks.
I don't know if this is a hell of a coincidence but it started to happen after upgrading to the 3.70 firmware.

Has anybody been facing the same problem? Are there any fixes  to this issue?

Comment: It seems [someone else has this problem as well](http://www.digital-forums.com/showthread.php?855279-PS3-40Gb-FAT-bricked-after-Firmware-Upgrade-to-3.70-Help!)

Comment: Have you tried returning to factory settings?

Comment: In my case, at least, it was a hell of a coincidence. It happened to be a hardware problem (caused by the firmware upgrade???) that got fixed after changing a couple of chips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is still on warranty, returns back to PlayStation. Otherwise, you must pay a fee. My friend had the same problem and they have sent him a new one.